# Insert into table not working but no error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

Please help, I am new to php and trying to write a register page. No errors appear but the data doesn't appear in the database either. All of the validation works fine so I think there is something wrong when inserting into the table. Can anyone help?

```
<?php 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
require('connect_db.php');
$errors = array();


if(empty($_POST['firstname']))
    {
    $errors[]='Enter your Firstname';
    }
else 
    {
    $fn = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['firstname']));
    }


if(empty($_POST['surname']))
    {
    $errors[]='Enter your Surname';
    }
else 
    {
    $sn = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['surname']));
    }


if(empty($_POST['email']))
    {
    $errors[]='Enter your email address';
    }
else 
    {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['email']));
    }

if(!empty($_POST['pass1']))
    {
        if($_POST['pass1']!= $_POST['pass2'])
            {
                $errors[] = 'Passwords do not match';   
            }
        else
            {
                $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['pass1']));
            }
    }
else
    {
        $errors[]="Enter your password";
    }

if (empty($errors))
    {
        $q = "INSERT INTO Users(Username, Firstname, Surname, Password)
            VALUES($email, $fn, $sn,  User, SHA1($p))";
        $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
        if ($r)
        {
            echo "success";
        }
    }
else 
    {
        echo '<h1>Error</h1><p id="errors">The following error/s occurred:<br/>';
        foreach ($errors as $error)
            {
                echo"$error <br/>";

            }
        echo"Please try again</p>";
        mysqli_close($dbc);
    }
```

}

Comment: This question was caused by a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing quotes around your string values:

```
INSERT INTO Users(Username, Firstname, Surname, Password)
        VALUES($email, $fn, $sn,  User, SHA1($p))
```

should be:

```
INSERT INTO Users(Username, Firstname, Surname, Password)
        VALUES('$email', '$fn', '$sn',  'User', 'SHA1($p)')
```

The reason you get an error is you're not actually checking for any. You need to add an else statement when you check the value of `$r` and in there call [`mysqli_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to see your error message.

```
if ($r) {
    echo "success";
}
else {
    echo mysqli_error($dbc); exit// this really should be better then this.
}
```

Comment: I thought of that, too. The author of the question only states that no errors appear, but how should they? If the word "success" does not appear, then there was an error with the SQL.

Comment: it says no database selected

Comment: There you go. You have an error in `connect_db.php`. You need to verify that code is correct.